# Stack view hides views, stacked in it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I've been struggling with autolayout lately and decided to use UIStackViews to make interface fit all screen sizes. But somehow those stacks ruined everything. I decided to create test project to track, how stackviews work, but it's still a complete mystery to me.
So I have this view hierarchy 
[image: Interface builder]
I have a stack, that embeds 2 views and 1 label. Each of these views contains a label, that is constrained by xCenter of it's superview. All three of these labels have the same yCenter, which is the yCenter of a stackView. Stack View is constraint by leading, trailing and bottom guide constraints.
But somehow, it's shown absolutely not the same in the simulator. What can be the reason of it?[image: Simulator]
Colorful views are gone, labels are messed up, I'm puzzled.

I also have these warnings.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you configure the autolayout for the stackview? 
If I create a similar project like your example, the views fills the whole stackview. I attached the UIStackView to the top, bottom, left and right edges using autolayout.
[image: XCode screenshot]

Comment: Did you somehow constraint views, embedded in a stack view?

Comment: Yes, the first two views (orange and white) is 100px wide, the last view (red) just fills the rest.

Comment: I used centered alignment, that's why it was so messed up. When set to fill, it works good